# Динамическое обновление данных из одной таблицы в другую

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

Второй день вожусь с обновлением таблиц, есть успехи, как и имеются значительные трудности.
Это функция

```
 function getExpToNextPower_price_up($user_id)
{
    $query = R::getRow("SELECT `powers`.`power_price` FROM powers
                        JOIN `users` ON `users`.`power_lvl` = `powers`.`power_lvl` 
                        WHERE `users`.`id` = {$user_id}");
    return $query['power_price'];
}

function getExpToHerePower_price_up($user_power_price, $user_power_lvl)
{
    $query = R::getRow("SELECT {$user_power_lvl} - powers_lvl FROM powers
                        WHERE power_price = {$user_power_lvl}");
    return $query["{$power_price} - power_lvl"];
}
function updateUserPower_price_up($user_id, $user_power_lvl)
{
    $update_to_power_price_up = R::getRow("SELECT MAX(power_price) FROM `powers` WHERE power_lvl ={$user_power_lvl} ");
    R::exec('UPDATE `users` SET `power_price` = :power_price WHERE id = :id', [
        'id' => $user_id,
        'power_price_up' => $update_to_power_price_up['MAX(power_price']
    ]);
    
    $user = R::load('users', $user_id);
    return $user;
  }
```

Переменная

```
updateUserPower_price_up($user->id, $user->power_lvl);
```

Ошибка Fatal error: Uncaught [HY093] - SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined trace: #0 D:\OpenServer\domains\vargs.mobi\libs\redbean\rb-mysql.php(1162): RedBeanPHP\Driver\RPDO->runQuery() #1 D:\OpenServer\domains\vargs.mobi\libs\redbean\rb-mysql.php(4163): RedBeanPHP\Driver\RPDO->Execute() #2 D:\OpenServer\domains\vargs.mobi\libs\redbean\rb-mysql.php(11645): RedBeanPHP\Adapter\DBAdapter->exec() #3 D:\OpenServer\domains\vargs.mobi\libs\redbean\rb-mysql.php(12695): RedBeanPHP\Facade::query() #4 D:\OpenServer\domains\vargs.mobi\core\functions.php(127): RedBeanPHP\Facade::exec() #5 D:\OpenServer\domains\vargs.mobi\init.php(38): updateUserPower_price_up() #6 D:\OpenServer\domains\vargs.mobi\index.php(3): include_once('D:\OpenServer\d...') #7 {main} thrown in D:\OpenServer\domains\vargs.mobi\libs\redbean\rb-mysql.php on line 810

Что именно делаю не так?

Answer (score 1):

Эта ошибка сигнализирует о проблемах с плейсхолдерами. Под словом parameter здесь имеется в виду именно он. То есть, "parameter was not defined" означает, что мы пытаемся привязать к запросу плейсхолдер, которого в нем нет.

Например, мы определили в запросе плейсхолдер, но ошиблись при его написании его имени в массиве:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('UPDATE t SET name = : WHERE id = :name');
$stmt->execute(['mane' => $name, 'id' => $id]));
```

PDO попытается найти в запросе плейсхолдер с именем 'mane', не найдет его, и выдаст эту самую ошибку!

<sub>(взято отсюда http://phpfaq.ru/pdo/parameter_was_not_defined)</sub>

---

Если внимательно посмотреть в запрос, то никакого `power_price_up` там нет, который пытаешься всунуть потом в ключе массива

Comment: Можешь дать наводку с какой функции идёт ошибка?

Comment: Написано же в трейсе что из updateUserPower_price_up() #6

Comment: Ладно, спасибо и на этом. Над все переварить и подумать.